# Add the same element name using BEM methodology

Tags: html, css, bem

I started to use BEM methodology and i have a question according to this.
Example:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__block-1">
    <h1 class="container-title">block1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container__block-2">
    <h1 class="container__title container-title">block2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container__block-3">
    <h1 class="container__title container-title">block3</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

How you can see i use: `container__title` element in block 2 and in block3. I need this to add different margin and padding for `h1`.
**Question: Can i use the same `element` in `container__block-2` and `container__block-3` according to `BEM` methodology?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is okay to use the same element for another block as long as you want to have the same properties of the above blocks.

However, incase you need a variation, that's when the `modifier` comes into role.

whenever you need to make a change in only a particular element from a group of elements, you use a modifier there. It is denoted as `block__element--modifier`.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__block-1">
    <h1 class="container-title">block1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container__block-2">
    <h1 class="container__title container__title--modifier1 ">block2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container__block-3">
    <h1 class="container__title container__title--modifier2">block3</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For different variants of same class, u can use `--`

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__block-1">
    <h1 class="container-title">block1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container__block-2">
    <h1 class="container__title container__title--1">block2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container__block-3">
    <h1 class="container__title container__title--2">block3</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```